# Migrating my flutter plugin to Android Embedded V2

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

I have this Flutter plugin, I want to migrate it to Android-embedded V2. But I am getting an error when I execute it.

The following is a small part of the code.

```
class FitkitPlugin() : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {

  private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

  private var activity: Activity? = null

  private var deferredResult: Result? = null

  constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
    }


 companion object {
    private const val TAG = "FitKit"

    const val GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 19

    @JvmStatic
    public fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
        val instance = ExperionFitkitPlugin(registrar.activity())
        val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "experion_fitkit")
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(instance)
        }
    }

  init {
        registrar.addActivityResultListener { requestCode, resultCode, _ ->
            println("Inside on activity result")
            var result = false
            if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    deferredResult?.success(true)
                    deferredResult = null
                } else {
                    deferredResult?.error("canceled", "User cancelled or app not authorized", null)
                    deferredResult = null
                }
                result = true
            }
            result
        }
    }



}
```

But When I try to execute the project I get an error `Unresolved reference: registrar`

How can I resolve this?